# How to call a Umbraco API

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco

I was unable to connect to Umbraco API from my application, I am getting error as"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized". I have added cms.dll and businesslogic.dll as a reference file to my application from Umbraco Project.

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.member;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.propertytype;

namespace UmbracoCreateMember
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Member.GetMemberFromEmail(txtEmail.Text) == null)
            {
                MemberType demoMemberType = new MemberType(1040); //id of membertype 'demo'
                Member newMember = Member.MakeNew(txtName.Text, demoMemberType, new umbraco.BusinessLogic.User(0));

                newMember.Email = txtEmail.Text;
                newMember.Password = txtPassword.Text;
                newMember.LoginName = txtUsername.Text;

                newMember.getProperty("address").Value = txtAddress.Text; //set value of property with alias 'address'
                newMember.getProperty("city").Value = txtCity.Text; //set value of property with alias 'city'

                newMember.Save();
            }else
            {
                //member exists
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ScreenShot:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must specify in the Web.config file the ConnectionString of your umbraco instance

Comment: Yes, this. It will be an issue with the connection string in the web.config

Comment: But how is the connection string will be to connect the umbraco project. I have done with SQL server previously. But this is the first time with umbraco project. Can I have the sample?

Comment: Test it :http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/29269-How-I-can-get-connection-string-by-API